# Formula to format cell if time has passed?

Tags: excel, google-drive-api, google-sheets, excel-formula

For a list of times like so:

```
08:00
08:30
09:00
09:30
...
```

what formula would select cells containing times that have passed for the current day, assuming only the time (not the full date) was stored in the cell? Ideally something that works in Google Drive too.

I tried comparing them to `NOW()` but it didn't work, presumably because `NOW()` compares to a full date, but I only want to compare an hour and minute to the current hour and minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare to `(NOW()-TODAY())`

(Not sure if it will work in Google...)

Comment: Love the simplicity — and it does work in Drive. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This formula will do it:

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(NOW());MINUTE(NOW());SECOND(NOW()))>A1;TRUE;FALSE)
```

Assuming that the time you want to check is in the cell A1.
The formula returns TRUE or FALSE...

**Explanation:** You can't use "now" alone, because as you say, that's a date. So you need to extract hour, minute and seconds from "now" and create a time value out of it.